# How to overwrite an existing table in synapse azure?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

back my table in to the sql pool. However whenever i do changes and try to overwrite the table,i could not. I always need to create a new table.
Is there any way i can overwrite the existing table:
Below is the code:

```
%%spark
val scala_df = spark.sqlContext.sql ("select * from result_pdf")
scala_df.write.synapsesql("yogesh.dbo.result2_pdf", Constants.INTERNAL)

Error : java.sql.SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: There is already an object named 'result2_pdf' in the database.
```

Comment: I too facing same issue. Did you found any solution?

Comment: new_df = spark.createDataFrame(vendor_segmentation_output)
new_df.createOrReplaceTempView("pysparkdftemptable")

val scala_df = spark.sqlContext.sql ("select * from pysparkdftemptable") 
scala_df.write.mode("Overwrite").parquet("/sparkextract/Vendor_Segmentation/Dim_AP_vendor_SegmentTemp.parquet")

Comment: I transformed into parquet format

Answer (score 0):

The write API creates the table in the dedicated SQL pool and then invokes Polybase to load the data.

> The table must not exist in the dedicated SQL pool or an error will be returned stating that "`There is already an object named...`"

**Reference:** [Azure Synapse Analytics - Write API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-spark-sql-pool-import-export#write-api)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to drop the existing table through spark query before creating new.